# Java Service - Keep threads going while waiting for PUT requests

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, amazon-kinesis

I have a Java service on a Tomcat server that will receive HTTP PUT json messages, and will then send them into a Kinesis Stream on AWS. Currently, it has a PUT method that will take a message, do some data manipulations to it, generate the credentials, initialize the connection to the stream, and then write to that stream. I'm hoping to instead have this service have a thread that generate credentials/connect to the stream and store them in a Kinesis client object, sleeps until the creds expire, and meanwhile the service listens for PUT requests and writes to Kinesis using that client object before regenerating/reconnecting when they expire after a period of time. To me, this seems far more efficient instead of trying to generate/connect each time I get a PUT request.

I'm fairly new to web services, and am wanting to make sure this is something feasible. Essentially, I believe the service would need to be running on the server non-stop, between requests as well, in order to keep the Kinesis client object (which is connected to the stream). Are there any resources anyone can give me to help me set it up for this purpose?

Comment: Of course it's feasible. Just like you don't create a new connection to the database each time you need to perform an operation. It would be incredibly ineffective.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Currently my servlet class just has a method with a @PUT header that consumes the message. Add a run() method that starts a thread for the credentials/kinesis connection maybe, and then how would I then have it listen for the HTTP requests constantly while its sleeping?

Comment: Sleeping is for babies, not for threads working at your server. I recommend digging deep into the documentation, you might learn some standard ideoms at the same time. It's a bit too broad to get into webapp design in this question.